# Why do halobenzenes not give Birch reduction?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, organic-reduction

I was studying Birch reduction and my book says halobenzene and phenol do not give Birch reduction. I want to know why these two type of compounds do not give Birch reduction.

I also want to know if using reagents of Birch reduction on halobenzene would give halocyclohexane.

[image]

Comment: Phenol is acidic and reacts with the Na metal to give sodium phenoxide which is not going to reduce under these conditions

Comment: What about chlorobenzene?

Comment: I don't think it would work like that.

Comment: Ok. Maybe book is wrong. Sometimes this happen.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1021%2Fja01407a038

Answer (score 2):

Birch reduction of chlorobenzene has been achieved using gas-phase hydrated electrons $\ce{(H2O)_n^−}$, n = 30–65 leading to formation of a chloro-cyclohexadienyl radical $\ce{C6H6Cl.}$<sup>1</sup>.

Birch reduction of phenolic species has been achieved with β-napthol and some of its derivatives. They have further said that such systems are nearly impossible to undergo reduction is due to high potential energy barrier to electron addition to the phenolate anion to form the required dianion radical intermediate<sup>2</sup>. But still theoretical studies are still made on this reaction on such species along with system containing other substituents like $\ce{CH3, CN, COOH, NO2, OCH3, NH2}$ to understand the stability of cyclohexadienyl and homocyclopentadienyl anion<sup>3</sup>.

**References**

1. Yali Cao, Robert F. Höckendorf, Martin K. Beyer,
   *Birch reduction of chlorobenzene in gas-phase hydrated electrons*,
   International Journal of Mass Spectrometry,
   Volume 277, Issues 1–3, **2008**, DOI: [10.1016/j.ijms.2008.05.025](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1387380608002042)
2. *Birch Reduction of Phenols*, Josef. Fried, N. A. Abraham, and T. S. Santhanakrishnan, Journal of the American Chemical Society **1967** 89 (4), 1044-1045, DOI: [10.1021/ja00980a063](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja00980a063)
3. A theoretical approach to the Birch reduction. Structures and stabilities of cyclohexadienyl anions, Arthur J. Birch, Alan L. Hinde, and Leo Radom, Journal of the American Chemical Society **1980** 102 (21), 6430-6437, DOI: 10.1021/ja00541a009